# Why this Joda offset cannot get daylightsaving right

Tags: timezone, jodatime, dst

I have the following code using Joda to calculate offset for any given day, for example

```
int offset = DateTimeZone.forID("EST").getOffset(new DateTime(2013,8,1,1,1));
```

this will give me offset of -18000000. But for:

```
 int offset = DateTimeZone.forID("EST").getOffset(new DateTime(2012,12,1,1,1));
```

this also give me offset of -18000000.

Looks like daylightsaving is not taken in to calculation. Anyone knows why? Thanks.

I am using Joda-time-2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly telling it to ignore Daylight Savings Time.

EST is Eastern Standard Time, notably different than EDT, which is Daylight Savings Time.

Instead, try using the ID US/Eastern, so

```
DateTimeZone.forID("US/Eastern")
```

A complete list of the time zones available can be found [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). US/Eastern is an alias for America/New_York

Comment: I checked the list. Isn't EST also under the list? So should we use "Canonical ID" or "Alias"?

Comment: Either Canonical ID or Alias should be fine. The issue with EST is that EST stands for Eastern Standard Time. Eastern Standard Time is not the same as colloquially saying "Eastern". Eastern Standard Time is explicitly Eastern time when it is not daylight savings. In order to get Daylight savings, I'd recommend using either US/Eastern or America/New_York.

Answer (score 0):

You're expected to give a time zone ID - not the abbreviation for "half" a time zone. So for example, `America/New_York` is one example of a time zone ID for Eastern Time (there are others, for time zones which may be like New York now, but weren't historically, etc).

```
import org.joda.time.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
        System.out.println(zone.getOffset(new DateTime(2013,8,1,1,1)));
        System.out.println(zone.getOffset(new DateTime(2012,12,1,1,1)));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
-14400000
-18000000
```

You should stay away from the abbreviated forms as far as possible - they're ambiguous (non-unique) and usually only define one part of a time zone. Ick.

Comment: Quoting your [OMG PONIES!!! (AKA HUMANITY: EPIC FAIL)](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/) presentation:  "Yes, CST is there three times. Once for Central Standard Time in the US – which is UTC-6. It’s also Central Standard Time in Australia – where it’s UTC+9.30. It’s also Central Summer Time in Australia, where it’s UTC+10.30. I think it takes a special kind of incompetence to use the same acronym in the same place for different offsets."