# Insert UTC timestamp into MySQL - Daylight Savings timezone

Tags: java, mysql, timezone, utc, dst

I have a Java client that is inserting (through a CSV and 'LOAD DATA INFILE') timestamps (type TIMESTAMP) in UTC format in a MySQL DB. My server's timezone is "America/New_York" and I need to keep daylight savings information. November 5th at 2:00am is when the time changes from EDT to EST and clocks are set back one hour to 1:00AM. So November 5th 1:30 AM, for instance, happens twice; once in EDT and once in EST.

How can I make the server distinguish between the two? For instance, if I want to insert '2017-11-05 01:30:00' EDT, is there a way to tell MySQL to tell the difference between '2017-11-05 01:30:00' EDT (before the time change) and '2017-11-05 01:30:00' EST (after the time change) when I insert values? My Java application has the timezone information of both timestamps if that matters.

I want to keep the server's global timezone as 'America/New_York' because users access this data and want it displayed in their local time.

The solution I thought of is to set the connection's timezone to UTC from the Java client, insert the values in UTC and then reset the connection's timezone back, but I wanted to know if there was a better, more 'standard' solution.

Comment: If the value is in UTC, there's no DST ambiguity. `2017-11-05T01:30 EDT` is the same as `2017-11-05T05:30 UTC` and `2017-11-05T01:30:00 EST` is `2017-11-05T06:30 UTC`.

Comment: I know. My question is, I have 2 timestamps in Java. One is '2017-11-05 01:30:00' EDT and the other one is '2017-11-05 01:30:00' EST. How can I insert both in the MySQL field of type TIMESTAMP, which is UTC? Do I need to convert them to UTC in Java first and then insert them, or is there a better way?

Comment: When you say *timestamp*, do you mean a `java.sql.Timestamp` or another type?

Comment: I have it as a ZonedDateTime at the moment

Comment: I know that JDBC 4.2 has support to `java.time` classes, and I guess most major database vendors already implemented the respective drivers. So, I believe that just converting the `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` (calling `toInstant()` method) and saving the `Instant` might work. Or, for JDBC < 4.2, you can convert it to a `java.sql.Timestamp` using `Timestamp.from(zoneddatetime.toInstant())` and save the timestamp (I used mysql a long time ago, but I think that `Timestamp` and `Instant` classes are mapped to TIMESTAMP fields - but I would check the docs just to make sure)

Answer (score 0):

use jodaTime api with newYork or eastern time zone
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
[Why this Joda offset cannot get daylightsaving right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454021/why-this-joda-offset-cannot-get-daylightsaving-right)

Comment: Although a great API, Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."** - Anyway, OP told that is using `ZonedDateTime` (Java 8), so there's really no reason to use Joda-Time.